# Vue Axios - token is undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I have a Vue SPA and I'm using Axios for handling requests, vue-axios to apply it and vuex for storing tokens. But when I send a request the header **Authorization** becomes **Bearer undefined** or **Bearer null**.

The flow is that by logging in I retrieve a token, save it to the session storage, dispatch a login action and my vuex store will set a token in the state from the session storage. After my login and router redirect to "/" I want to send a GET request to /foo along with my token. But here my token is undefined. Based on console logs I know that the session storage do have the token before the request is sent.

I am following the structure from [this](https://paweljw.github.io/2017/09/vue.js-front-end-app-part-3-authentication/) tutorial by Paweljw:

**Axios/axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://example.com/api/,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
  }
})
```

**Axios/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from './axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export default Vue;
```

**Components/login.vue**

```
onLogin(res) {
  if (!res.data.token) {
    return this.onLoginFailed();
  }

  sessionStorage.token = res.data.token;

  this.$store.dispatch("login");
  this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || "/");
```

**Components/foo.vue**

```
...
this.$http
    .get("foo")
    .then(res => this.doSomething(res))
    .catch(() => this.doSomethingElse());
```

As previously mentioned this sends a request with **Bearer undefined**. I'm aware that when axios.create(...) is being exported the sessionStorage.token is null - it hasn't been set when the application starts. And that's probably why, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to set it then and how other people using the same tutorial doesn't have this issue.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can easily create axios instance and have convenient access from vue with
 [this package](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/vue-plugin-axios/graphs/traffic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this tutorial may have a mistake - if you set your headers in `axios.create` then the `Authorization` header will get the current value of the sessionStorage, which at this time is `undefined`.

Actually, you want to set your headers in `axios.interceptors.request.use` - so that the header will be populated with the value of the sessionStorage at the moment of performing the AJAX request. Something like this

```
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios.create(
  {
    headers:
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  }
);

Vue.prototype.$axios.interceptors.request.use(
  config =>
  {
    if (store.getters.isUserLoggedin) config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + store.getters.user.token;
    return config;
  }
);

Vue.prototype.$axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error =>
  {
    if (error && error.response && error.response.status && error.response.status === 403)
    {
      store.dispatch('unsetUser');
      router.push('/login');
      return Promise.resolve(); // Avoid showing any errors
    }
    else
    {
      logger.error({
        message: 'Error in HTTP request',
        response: JSON.stringify(extractError(error)),
        status: _get(error, 'response.status', 'unknown'),
        url: _get(error, 'config.url', 'unknown'),
        userId: store.getters.userInfo.id
      });
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: It's working like a charm now, thank you so much! On a sidenote for other users: if you're using tokens you should add the "Bearer" type to the Authorization header.